# Creating a plot with multiple pandas datadframes-Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to built a code in which for approximate 100 .txt files that I open from a folder I generate a unique plot of the dataframes, in which I select just the first two columns. This is my code, which unfortunately doesn't work at all (I got 100 different plots)

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

file_location = os.path.join('files','*.txt')
filenames = glob.glob(file_location)


for f in filenames:
  outfile = pd.read_csv(f, nrows=310, sep=" ", header=None)
  df = pd.DataFrame(outfile)
  data = df.iloc[:, 0:2]
  data.columns = ['x','y']
  #print(data) 

  for frame in data:
     data.plot(x="x",y="y", alpha=0.5)
```

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do the plotting using the `pyplot` object itself, so you can handle the plotting behavior better. In your case, the following modification works:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

for f in filenames:
  df = pd.read_csv(f, nrows=310, sep=" ", header=None)

  # the df = pd.DataFrame(outputfile) is unecessary. pd.read_csv
  # returns a data frame in the first place

  data = df.iloc[:, 0:2]
  data.columns = ['x','y']

  plt.plot(data.x, data.y, alpha=0.5, color='blue')

plt.show() # or plt.savefig()
```

If you don't specify the `color` every dataframe will be plotted with a unique color